# Can we make aliases for the commands with parameters

Tags: alias

I want to make alias for:

- `rm -rf *` => `#rm -rf *`
- `rm *` => `#rm *`

When I type `rm -rf *`, I want it to be commented out and not take action.

[Q] General question is can we make generate aliases for the commands with parameters?

Comment: Provide a better explanation of your problem

Comment: There is really not much to say, I am just asking does aliases contain space exist or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create alias with spaces, i.e. something like below is invalid:

```bsh
alias 'rm -rf *'='#rm -rf *'
```

But of course you can create alias for commands with parameters:

```bsh
alias foo='#rm -rf *'
```

Although from the examples from your question, looks like you want to put `#` before every `rm`. To do so, you need to only alias `rm`:

```bsh
alias rm='#rm'
```

If you wanted to only "disable" `rm` for `-rf`, then you would need to write a wrapper function:

```bsh
rm() {
    if [ "$1" != "-rf" ]; then
        rm $@
    fi
}
```

---

> Can I disable only for `rm -rf *` but keeping other `rm -rf` if `*` is not included?

Yes, you can. For example:

```bsh
rm() {
    if [ "$1" != "-rf" ]; then
        rm $@
    else
        shift 1
        x="$@"
        if [ "$x" != "$(echo *)" ]; then
            rm -rf $@
        fi
    fi
}
```

Comment: Can I disable only for `rm -rf *` but keeping other `rm -rf` if `*` is not included?

Comment: Yes, you can do that

Comment: Can I generate this function in ZSH, it gives following error: `zsh: parse error near `()'`

Comment: I've just tested it in Zsh and it works

Comment: Should I paste it directly into terminal or into `.bashrc` and call it?

Comment: Neither. If you paste into terminal, you will get it only for the current session. To make it "permanent" you need to put it into configuration file. You want to have it in Zsh, so the file would be `.zshrc` (`.bashrc` is for Bash)

Comment: If I make the function name `rmm() {` I don't  get the error , but instead if its `rm() ` the parse error shows up

Comment: @alper I may require a new question "_Why Zsh gives a parse error for my wrapper for `rm`?_"

Comment: Sure: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/598418/why-zsh-gives-a-parse-error-for-my-wrapper-for-rm